# TimeZone change the Current day

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using the (moment.js) for getting the day of the week.
I am using this method to create a date object:

```
var keyDateObj = moment("2014-01-22 00:00:00 "+ "+0000", "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD");
```

But when i am asking for the `isoWeekday()` for the same date with different time zone (india and USA).
The result is different for the time zone

- india - 3
- USA - 2.

My question is when the date is same how can day of the week is different.

Comment: The code you show does not demonstrate the problem you describe. In order to fully understand what you are asking, please provide code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The weekday of a date given as UTC is relative to the time zone. As India is a few hours ahead and the USA are a few hours behind, the ISO weekday will be different (because in the respective time zones it actually `is` a different day).

Example:

```
2014-01-22 00:00:00 +0000   // this means it is January 22 in London for example
// the weekday is Wednesday
```

has the following representation for USA east coast

```
2014-01-21 19:00:00 -0500   // this means it is January 21 in New York at the "same time"
// the weekday is Tuesday
```

Comment: I have used the same date "2014-01-22" in both the cases and also var keyDateObj = moment("2014-01-22 00:00:00 "+ "+0000", "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD"); return the same date for both the zone. SO my question is if date is same then how can time zone effect for the isoWeekday?

Comment: Your code generates only _one_ UTC timestamp, and that is independend of any time zone. (So _“return the same date for both the zone”_ is a statement that does not make any sense.) Once you have this UTC timstamp _interpreted_ in different local timezone though, you get these differences – naturally, because at one and the same actual point in time the _local_ time in the US and India are different.

Comment: @CBroe is there any solution for this. I have a date string i need to just get day corresponding to date(Timezone should not be consider).

Comment: @Techie there is a solution. Use the Timezone. It is impossible to get the day correct if you don't use timezone.